# How do i display total item in cart just behind cart icon

Tags: php, css, icons, cart

Am new to css i just got few during reseach but in achievement i want the total item in cart to display just behind my cart icon like this:

[image: example]

My code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
echo "<style type='text/css'>
    .cart {
        background-image: url('cart.png');
    }

    </style>";
echo "<div class='cart'></div>";
} else {
  $totalquantity = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
             $totalquantity += $each_item[quantity];
            }
echo "<div class='cart'>$totalquantity</div>";
}
?>
```

Big thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look into "position: relative".  Then have a div with two images.  The second image would have something like "top: 20px; left: -1;"

Comment: Please in real team i have no code about my question just which to achieve if is really possible

Comment: if the question is only about the html and css required you may achieve better results by *only* placing the rendered html in the post instead of the php code generating it since this post is not tagged with `PHP`

Comment: @happymacarts
i really need soluction php is tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what Bootstrap uses

Using the css pseudo selector `:empty` allows it to auto collapse when there is no content

this way in your php you can always render the "<span class="badge"><?php $totalquantity;?></span>"

```css
.container {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.cart {
  background-image: url('http://www.pvhc.net/img180/xewlwqfroahrisfwokkc.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 3px solid #8174f7;
  position: absolute ;
  right:8px;
  top:8px;
}

.badge {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.badge:empty {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding:8px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:62px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='cart'>
    <span class="badge">4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Tot. odd: <span class="red">40.04</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Your PHP code may look something like this**

```
<?php 

echo "<style>... the styles above</style>" ;
/*
load your styles before content is rendered
they should be loaded in a a separate css file but that's up to you

*/


$totalquantity = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) ) {
      foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
         $totalquantity += $each_item[quantity];
        }
?>
<div class='cart'><?php echo $totalquantity;?></div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Yes thanks at first but I dont really no how to say this not as expected Call it echo "<div class='cart'>
      <span class='badge'>$totalquantity</span>
    </div>";
just after my header but i get outputed top my page just with the logo
my expectation output should be were it were called

eg
_________________________________________________________________________show here
____________________________

but i get as

___________________show here
_______________________________________________________

Comment: not sure what this comment means?

I think i understand the issue.  You did not output the "container" div i created which is what initializes the Position relative. with out it you are getting an absolute positioned element